# With log4j, is it possible to hide JDBC returned column values with org.hibernate.type TRACE logging enabled?

Tags: hibernate, jdbc, log4j

I'm tracking Hibernate's generated SQL statements and their bound parameters using log4j on a Seam Framework project. Currently I have the below configuration:

**jboss-log4j.xml**:

```
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/" debug="false">

...

   <appender name="SQL" class="org.jboss.logging.appender.DailyRollingFileAppender">
      <errorHandler class="org.jboss.logging.util.OnlyOnceErrorHandler"/>
      <param name="File" value="${jboss.server.log.dir}/sql.log"/>
      <param name="Append" value="true"/>
      <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
         <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{ABSOLUTE} [%c{1}] %X{username} %m%n"/>
      </layout>
   </appender>

   <category name="org.hibernate">
       <priority value="INFO"/>
       <appender-ref ref="SQL"/>
   </category>

   <category name="org.hibernate.SQL" additivity="false">
       <priority value="DEBUG"/>
       <appender-ref ref="SQL"/>
   </category>

   <category name="org.hibernate.HQL" additivity="false">
       <priority value="DEBUG"/>
       <appender-ref ref="SQL"/>
   </category>

   <category name="org.hibernate.type" additivity="false">
       <priority value="TRACE"/>
       <appender-ref ref="SQL"/>
   </category>

</log4j:configuration>
```

The problem is the generated sql.log file becomes too unwieldy as at least 100k of text is appended to the log on each page visit. I would like to filter out the JDBC messages for "returning  as column " and instead only track INSERT/UPDATE queries but can't find such an option in Hibernate or log4j's documentation. Removing these lines using a manual scripting process isn't desirable since I want to reduce disk reads/writes on the web server.

Is it possible to stop these returned JDBC values of SELECT queries from being added to the log file while keeping the parameter value bindings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately both logging statements:

```
binding '...' to parameter: ...
```

and

```
returning '...' as column: ...
```

originate from the same class `org.hibernate.type.NullableType` and are logged on the same `TRACE` level. This means that you can't simply filter the latter log statement leaving the first one untouched.

However, if you are using [Logback](http://logback.qos.ch), [filters](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/filters.html) might come to the rescue.

Comment: Thanks. I actually found placing a `<filter class="org.apache.log4j.varia.StringMatchFilter">` inside the `<appender name="SQL" class="org.jboss.logging.appender.DailyRollingFileAppender">` works to filter out any strings containing "Returning", "returning", "/* select", or "/* criteria query */ select". The latest log4j 1.2.10 also supports regex, so you can use: `<param name="RegexToMatch" value="([rR]eturning (null|'[^']+') as column: )|(/\* criteria query \*/ select)|(/* select )" />` although parameter bindings for SELECT queries are still logged.

Comment: So the filtering approach was fruitful, glad I could help.

Comment: @DerekMacDonald: I can't find anything like "RegexToMatch" anywhere. Could you provide further info/links?